# How I redirect with link in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i used one link in my asp.net mvc project like this way.

```
 <a 
href="<%= Url.Action("DisplayAction", "TempController") %>" title="Display" 
/>
```

it works properly in calling controller.But,i want to call normal aspx in 
that way.

For eg,

```
 <a href="<%= Response.Redirect "WebForm.aspx" %>" title="Display" />
```

Please give me right ways.

Regards

Indi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to navigate to a normal page the standard way from HTML, you just set the `href` of the anchor attribute:

```
<a href="WebForm.aspx" title="Display">Link Text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

For MVC5, this one worked for me:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("AboutUs","OASiteContent")" type="submit" class="lnkbtn lnkbtn_2 Rectangle">I'm new here</a>
```